# r multiple graphs on a single jpeg

Tags: r, graph, jpeg

I have run into the following problem and I would appreciate if someone could give me some input.

I would like to export multiple figures to a single jpeg file. I first create a graphics lattice and then I export. My main issue is that it works with the pdf and not the jpeg. Any ideas?

Thank you

```
#set the windows of the frames
par(mfcol=c(3,2))

#create the jpeg file
jpeg(filename=names(a1),".jpg",sep=""),
     quality=100,
     width=1024,
     height=768)

#plot 1
plot(a1,b1)
#plot 2
plot(a1,b2)
#plot 3
plot(a1,b3)

#plot 4
plot(a2, c1)
#plot 5
plot(a2, c2)
#plot 6
plot(a2, c3)

#dev.off shuts down the specified (by default the current) graphical device
#here it passes the picture to the file
dev.off()
```

Comment: You've omitted a significant portion of your code... If you could include working and repeatable code that replicates your issue it will help a lot. Is `names(a1)` a vector and you had a `paste` in there?  What did you do when you used `pdf`?  Do you mean to open a graphics device (`par(...)`) before your call to `jpeg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether you want multiple 1024x768 images in a single jpeg file - which doesn't make sense - are whether you want a single jpeg image containing the 6 plots.

As I said, JPEGs are not a multi-page format, unlike a PDF. Hence you can get R to export to multiple JPEG files but not have all the separate figures in one JPEG.

R's devices allow for wildcards in the filenames, so if you want the six plots exported to files `foo001.jpeg`, `foo002.jpeg`, `foo00x.jpeg` then you can use the following

```
jpeg(filename = "foo%03d.jpeg", ....)
.... # plotting commands here
dev.off()
```

What happens if you do multiple plots without the wildcard/placeholder is document in say `?jpeg`:

> ```
> If you plot more than one page on one of these devices and do not
> include something like ‘%d’ for the sequence number in ‘file’, the
> file will contain the last page plotted.
> ```

Devices that handle multiple pages because the underlying file format allows it can take multiple plots into the single file as there is makes sense, e.g. `pdf()` and `postscript()`. Those devices have argument `onefile` which can be used to indicate if multiple plots in a single file are required.

However, the `par(mfcol=c(3,2))` makes me think you want a 3x2 set of plots in the same device region. That is allowed, but you need to call `par()` **after** you open the `jpeg()` device, not before. What your code, as shown, does is split the active device into 3x2 plotting regions and then opens a new device which picks up the default parameters, not the ones you set on the device active before you called `jpeg()`. This is illustrated below:

```
> plot(1:10)
> dev.cur()
X11cairo 
       2 
> op <- par(mfrow = c(3,2))
> jpeg("~/foo.jpg")
> par("mfrow")
[1] 1 1
> dev.off()
X11cairo 
       2 
> par("mfrow")
[1] 3 2
```

Hence you want perhaps wanted something like:

```
jpeg(filename=names(a1),".jpg",sep=""), quality=100,
     width=1024, height=768)
op <- par(mfcol=c(3,2))
#plot 1
plot(a1,b1)
#plot 2
plot(a1,b2)
#plot 3
plot(a1,b3)
#plot 4
plot(a2, c1)
#plot 5
plot(a2, c2)
#plot 6
plot(a2, c3)
par(op)
dev.off()
```

?

Comment: Thank you Gavin! just to clarify, I wanted a single jpeg image containing the 6 plots. You are right, I opened the device before calling the jpeg. It worked really nicely. I attach my initial code but this time corrected and including a reproducible example.

Comment: No, you split the current device *and then* opened the `jpeg()` device. This might seem like nitpicking but this is why it didn't do what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code

```
#data
a1<-seq(1,20,by=1) 
b1<-seq(31,50,by=1)
b2<-seq(51,70,by=1)
b3<-seq(71,90,by=1)

#create the jpeg file
jpeg(filename="a.jpg",
     quality=100,
     width=1024,
     height=768)

#set the create the frames
par(mfcol=c(3,1))

#plot the graphs
plot(a1,b1)
plot(a1,b2)
plot(a1,b3)


#par(op)

#dev.off shuts down the specified (by default the current) graphical device
#here it passes the picture to the file
dev.off()
```